# How to speed up a sync with a host DB when returning to online

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an app on Android with Kotlin, using Firebase Real-time DB.

Is there any way to speed up sync with host DB when clients returning online from offline?

When clients go offline, they write new data in their local cache and sync with host DB when returning online.
The problem is, it takes 1～2 minutes to sync with host DB after returning to online.

I'd really appreciate if you give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved!

By calling a goOffline() method, and then calling a goOnline() method, a client instantly start to sync with a host server.

Hope it will help you!!!